# Sort DataFrame by a datetime object from Jan to dec

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe. Aggregating the datframe using the pandas groupby:

```
df.groupby(["Date", "company"]).producttyp.size().reset_index()
```

Results are displayed in the table below

```
      Date       company      producttyp
0   Apr-2020      proA1         15
1   Apr-2020      proB1         6
2   Apr-2020      probCC        12
3   Apr-2020      prouba        18
4   Feb-2020      pWC           4
5   Feb-2020      pCA           4
6   Feb-2020      prosu         3
7   Jan-2020      proku         11
8   Jan-2020      proyu         5
9   Jan-2020      prose         2
10  Mar-2020      proud         10
11  Mar-2020      pride         7
12  Mar-2020      proza         6
13  May-2020      proVVaG       40
14  May-2020      proAG         13
15  May-2020      proG          41
16  May-2020      PKWC          18
```

I will like the `DataFrame` to be sorted according to the `Date` column. Is there any work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way using `pd.to_datetime` to convert it to `01-01-2020` then sort it using `df.sort_values` and convert it back to `Jan-2020` format using `strftime`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.sort_values(by=['Date'], inplace=True)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
df

        Date  company  producttyp
8   Jan-2020    proyu           5
7   Jan-2020    proku          11
9   Jan-2020    prose           2
4   Feb-2020      pWC           4
5   Feb-2020      pCA           4
6   Feb-2020    prosu           3
12  Mar-2020    proza           6
11  Mar-2020    pride           7
10  Mar-2020    proud          10
0   Apr-2020    proA1          15
3   Apr-2020   prouba          18
2   Apr-2020   probCC          12
1   Apr-2020    proB1           6
13  May-2020  proVVaG          40
14  May-2020    proAG          13
15  May-2020     proG          41
16  May-2020     PKWC          18
```

Answer (score 2):

Use, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `Date` column to the pandas datetime series and assign this to a temporary column in a grouped df, then use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort this dataframe on this temporary column, finally using [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) drop this temporary column:

```
df = (
    df.assign(temp=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%Y'))
    .sort_values(by='temp', ignore_index=True)
    .drop('temp', 1)
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

        Date  company  producttyp
0   Jan-2020    proyu           5
1   Jan-2020    proku          11
2   Jan-2020    prose           2
3   Feb-2020      pWC           4
4   Feb-2020      pCA           4
5   Feb-2020    prosu           3
6   Mar-2020    proza           6
7   Mar-2020    pride           7
8   Mar-2020    proud          10
9   Apr-2020    proA1          15
10  Apr-2020   prouba          18
11  Apr-2020   probCC          12
12  Apr-2020    proB1           6
13  May-2020  proVVaG          40
14  May-2020    proAG          13
15  May-2020     proG          41
16  May-2020     PKWC          18
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `Date` column is made of actual `datetime` objects, you can simply do:

```
df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

output:

```
          Date  company  producttyp
8  2020-01-01    proyu           5
7  2020-01-01    proku          11
9  2020-01-01    prose           2
4  2020-02-01      pWC           4
5  2020-02-01      pCA           4
6  2020-02-01    prosu           3
12 2020-03-01    proza           6
11 2020-03-01    pride           7
10 2020-03-01    proud          10
0  2020-04-01    proA1          15
3  2020-04-01   prouba          18
2  2020-04-01   probCC          12
1  2020-04-01    proB1           6
13 2020-05-01  proVVaG          40
14 2020-05-01    proAG          13
15 2020-05-01     proG          41
16 2020-05-01     PKWC          18
```

You may want to call `reset_index(drop=True)` afterwards if you don't need to keep the old, unsorted index.

If your `Date` column isn't made of `datetime` objects, you can convert it with:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Comment: I know this and its not in a datetime dtype

Comment: Then your question's title is phrased wrong. Either way, I've edited my answer and added the conversion.